# Printing unknown characters, not dashes and spaces, in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

Here are the relevant bits to my code:

```
//helper function that prints "------" lines or "      " lines
void li(char*  a, int len)
{
   int i;
      for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
          printf("%c",a);
        }
}

//helper function that prints out bar 
void bar(int length, int height)
{
     int i;
//prints out top line
     li("-", length);

//prints middle lines of spaces and "|"
     for (i=0;i<height-2;i++) {
     printf("\n");
     li(" ", 6);
     printf("|");
     li(" ", length-2);
     printf("|");
}
//prints bottom line
     if (height>=2){
     printf("\n");
     li(" ", 6);
     li("-", length);}
  return ;
}
```

Expected output:

```
The: ------------
     |          |
     ------------
```

Actual output

```
The: ��������������
     ������|�������������|
     ���������������������
```

^^Those should be unknown characters.

Anyways, I've tried to fix this problem, but have been unsuccessful so far. What's going on that's causing this to happen?

Comment: Passing a `char *` into `printf` when it expects a `char` is undefined behaviour and could very well cause that.

Comment: `printf("%c",*a);` Missing the `*`?

Comment: @Als: Should be `a[i]`, not `*a`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the way you have understood characters and strings.
To solve the problem you can change the signature of li(). Definition should look like

```
void li(char  a, int len)
{
   int i;
      for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
          printf("%c",a);
        }
}
```

And when calling the function li() use **single quote** instead of double quote.
`li("-", length);` should be `li('-', length);` and so on. 
I made the changes and run your code. Though it is not printing the characters as you expected, it is at least not printing unprintable characters.
Here is the code and output.

```
//helper function that prints "------" lines or "      " lines
void li(char  a, int len)
{
   int i;
      for (i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
          printf("%c",a);
        }
}

//helper function that prints out bar 
void bar(int length, int height)
{
     int i;
//prints out top line
     li('-', length);

//prints middle lines of spaces and "|"
     for (i=0;i<height-2;i++) {
     printf("\n");
     li(' ', 6);
     printf("|");
     li(' ', length-2);
     printf("|");
}
//prints bottom line
     if (height>=2){
     printf("\n");
     li(' ', 6);
     li('-', length);}
  return ;
}
main()
{
bar(5,5);
li('G',5);

}
```

Output :

```
-----
      |   |
      |   |
      |   |
      -----GGGGG
```

You can make changes to your code to make it print the way you want.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You want to print the character itself. Pass it the character, not a `char*`.

```
  printf("%c", *a);
```